# SOAP on Rails, can not call a method with WSDL using Savon

Tags: ruby-on-rails, soap, wsdl, savon

I want to use a financial institution webservice to "verifyTransaction" 
The method gets two strings as input and return a double as output.

```
double verifyTransaction (
String      RefNum, 
String      MerchantID
)
```

I used Savon in rails 3.1 to call the method.

```
client = Savon::Client.new do |wsdl|
    wsdl.document = "https://acquirer.sb24.com/ref-payment/ws/ReferencePayment?WSDL"
end

response = client.request :wsdl, "verifyTransaction" do
  soap.body ={"RefNum" => "ReferenceNumber", "MerchantID" => "MymerchantId"}
end
```

but the I got this error:

```
Savon::SOAP::Fault ((env:Client) caught exception while handling request: unexpected encoding style: expected=http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/, actual=)
```

Any thought on how to solve this?

Comment: Have you tried any of the other SOAP actions to see if this is consistent?

Comment: I get the same error with all SOAP actions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by using SoapUI.

I've opened the WSDL in SoapUI, generate a sample requests and copy/paste it into Savon like this:

```
client = Savon::Client.new do |wsdl|
    wsdl.document = "https://acquirer.sb24.com/ref-payment/ws/ReferencePayment?WSDL"
end

response = client.request "verifyTransaction" do
  soap.xml = 'XML will be here'
end
```

It worked fine! :)

Comment: you don't really need the wsdl if you are bypassing Savon by providing your own xml payload that way.

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't have valid information to actually try this, all I was able to do was get a HTTP 400 back instead of the other listed SOAP fault or a 500 response from the service.

Savon was setup with just the basics:

```
client = Savon::Client.new do
  wsdl.document = "https://acquirer.sb24.com/ref-payment/ws/ReferencePayment?WSDL"
end
```

The difference I found was specifying the namespace for the specific request.  Change the :wsdl out for "urn:Foo".

```
[26] pry(main)> client.request "urn:Foo", :verify_transaction do
[26] pry(main)*   soap.body = { "RefNum" => "1", "MerchantID" => "1" }  
[26] pry(main)* end
```

Debug output from the request:

```
D, [2011-10-31T09:05:17.202044 #1784] DEBUG -- : SOAP request: https://acquirer.sb24.com/ref-payment/ws/ReferencePayment
D, [2011-10-31T09:05:17.202314 #1784] DEBUG -- : SOAPAction: "verifyTransaction", Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8, Content-Length: 322
D, [2011-10-31T09:05:17.202414 #1784] DEBUG -- : <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><env:Envelope xmlns:urn:Foo="urn:Foo" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ins0="urn:Foo" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><env:Body><urn:Foo:verifyTransaction><MerchantID>1</MerchantID><RefNum>1</RefNum></urn:Foo:verifyTransaction></env:Body></env:Envelope>
D, [2011-10-31T09:05:17.202574 #1784] DEBUG -- : HTTPI executes HTTP POST using the httpclient adapter
D, [2011-10-31T09:05:18.780446 #1784] DEBUG -- : SOAP response (status 400):
D, [2011-10-31T09:05:18.780669 #1784] DEBUG -- : 
Savon::HTTP::Error: 
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/gems/savon-0.9.7/lib/savon/soap/response.rb:100:in `raise_errors'
```

### Longer Explanation

This is how I came up with the format above.

The namespacing can be important for some services.  Looking at the wsdl carefully, this is the actual action being used since the port reference is the "PaymentIF" port:

```
<message name="PaymentIF_verifyTransaction">
  <part name="String_1" type="xsd:string"/>
  <part name="String_2" type="xsd:string"/>
</message>
```

Within the port definition the actual message is referenced as "tns:PaymentIF_verifyTransaction":

```
<portType name="PaymentIF">
...
  <operation name="verifyTransaction" parameterOrder="String_1 String_2">
    <input message="tns:PaymentIF_verifyTransaction"/>
    <output message="tns:PaymentIF_verifyTransactionResponse"/>
  </operation>
...
</portType>
```

So looking back at the top again, the "tns" namespace is:

```
xmlns:tns="urn:Foo"
```

Comment: Thanks Nick, I tried this and I get HTTP Error 415 without any messages or details. I will copy/paste savons log in next comment:

Comment: `SOAP request: https://acquirer.sb24.com/ref-payment/ws/ReferencePayment
SOAPAction: "verifyTransaction", Content-Type: application/soap+xml;charset=UTF-8, Content-Length: 394
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><env:Envelope xmlns:urn:Foo="urn:Foo" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ins0="urn:Foo" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><env:Body><urn:Foo:verifyTransaction><MerchantID>1312312</MerchantID><RefNum>122132</RefNum></urn:Foo:verifyTransaction></env:Body></env:Envelope>
SOAP response (status 415)`

Comment: I tried changing "MerchantID" and "RefNum" to "String_1" and "String_2" but nothing changed! :(

Comment: I changed the content type to "text/xml" and now I get error 400!

Comment: I'm out of ideas at the moment.  I only ever seem to get back 400's regardless of what I change but that might be partly because of the proxy I'm currently behind.

Comment: I can't fix this 400 error. and I asked the webservice administrator and  he told me they do no receive any request, so their server probably return the request before processing it by the webservice. Can this be because of using HTTPS?

Comment: The request should still show up but usually in a separate log file for ssl.  Can you get an example transaction from them in xml of how both the request and response should look?

Comment: I asked them, they just referred me to their wsdl file.
Also I've looked into Error 400:
400 Bad Request This error code is used to indicate that either the HTTP request or the XML in the SOAP message was not well formed.

Comment: 1 more thing, I have used WSDLDriverFactory before using Savon, usin WSDLDriverFactory, the problem was that it generates XML files where all the arguments are empty. But I get the error from their webserver. I tried to embed that xml into savon using soap.xml ='The XML', no luck!

Comment: Here is that xml :
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <env:Body>
    <n1:verifyTransaction xmlns:n1="urn:Foo"
        env:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
      <String_1 xsi:nil="true"></String_1>
      <String_2 xsi:nil="true"></String_2>
    </n1:verifyTransaction>
  </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>`